# How to add custom page using them in wordpress 3.5

Tags: customization, themes

I did this before in wordpress 3.4 but that code seems not working. I add this code inside `wp-content/themes/` folder and I add new page from backend and try to select that. But it is not showing up, it's because new version..or am I doing it wrong?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Cover_Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
Here's my cover page!
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, first of all your page template has to be inside your **current** theme folder: `/wp-content/themes/current-theme/` or in a similar folder. Check the Codex ([Page Templates #File Folders](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#File_Folders)) to make sure your template is in the right folder.

While looking at the Codex also check the [Selecting a Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Selecting_a_Page_Template) section above if you did everything the right way. Your page templates are **only** visible for pages, so you'll not find them in the post section or somewhere else.